# Error when plotting DataFrame containing NaN with Pandas 0.12.0 and Matplotlib 1.3.1 on Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas, nan

First of all, this question is **not** the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603181/plot-pandas-dataframe-containing-nans).

The problem I'm having is that when I try to plot a DataFrame which contains a numpy NaN in one cell, I get an error:

```
C:\>\Python33x86\python.exe
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
>>> dates = pd.date_range('20131201', periods=5, freq='H')
>>> data = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [9, np.nan], [16, 17], [25, 26]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates,
...                       columns=list('AB'))
>>>
>>> print(df.to_string())
                      A   B
2013-12-01 00:00:00   1   2
2013-12-01 01:00:00   4   5
2013-12-01 02:00:00   9 NaN
2013-12-01 03:00:00  16  17
2013-12-01 04:00:00  25  26
>>> df.plot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1636, in plot_frame
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 856, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1240, in _make_plot
    self._make_ts_plot(data, **self.kwds)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1321, in _make_ts_plot
    _plot(data[col], i, ax, label, style, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1295, in _plot
    style=style, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\plotting.py", line 77, in tsplot
    lines = plotf(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4139, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 319, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 297, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 216, in _xy_from_xy
    by = self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1337, in update_units
    converter = munits.registry.get_converter(data)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py", line 137, in get_converter
    xravel = x.ravel()
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 3969, in ravel
    r._mask = ndarray.ravel(self._mask).reshape(r.shape)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 981, in reshape
    return ndarray.reshape(self, newshape, order)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

The above code works if I replace the np.NaN with a number, such as "2.3".

Plotting as two separate Series does not work either (it fails when I add the Series containing the NaN to the plot):

```
C:\>\Python33x86\python.exe
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
>>> dates = pd.date_range('20131201', periods=5, freq='H')
>>> data = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [9, np.nan], [16, 17], [25, 26]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates,
...                       columns=list('AB'))
>>>
>>> print(df.to_string())
                      A   B
2013-12-01 00:00:00   1   2
2013-12-01 01:00:00   4   5
2013-12-01 02:00:00   9 NaN
2013-12-01 03:00:00  16  17
2013-12-01 04:00:00  25  26
>>> df['A'].plot(label='This is A', style='k')
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x02ACFF90>
>>> df['B'].plot(label='This is B', style='g')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1730, in plot_series
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 856, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1240, in _make_plot
    self._make_ts_plot(data, **self.kwds)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1311, in _make_ts_plot
    _plot(data, 0, ax, label, self.style, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1295, in _plot
    style=style, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\plotting.py", line 77, in tsplot
    lines = plotf(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4139, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 319, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 297, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 216, in _xy_from_xy
    by = self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1337, in update_units
    converter = munits.registry.get_converter(data)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py", line 137, in get_converter
    xravel = x.ravel()
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 3969, in ravel
    r._mask = ndarray.ravel(self._mask).reshape(r.shape)
  File "C:\Python33x86\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 981, in reshape
    return ndarray.reshape(self, newshape, order)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

However, if I do this directly with Matplotlib's Pyplot plot(), instead of using Pandas' plot() function, it works:

```
C:\>\Python33x86\python.exe
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> dates = pd.date_range('20131201', periods=5, freq='H')
>>> plt.plot(dates, [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], 'k', dates, [2, 5, np.NAN, 17, 26], 'g')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x03E98650>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x040929B0>]
>>> plt.show()
>>>
```

So it seems that I have a workaround, but as I plot large DataFrames, I would prefer to use Pandas' plot() method, which is more convenient.
I've tried to follow the stack trace, but after a while it gets complicated (I'm not familiar with Pandas, Numpy and Matplotlib source code).
Am I doing something wrong, or is this a possible bug in Pandas' plot()?

Thank you for your help!

I tried both on Windows x86 and on Linux AMD64 with the same results with these versions:

- Python 3.3.2
- Pandas 0.12.0
- Matplotlib 1.3.1
- Numpy 1.7.1

Comment: I'm having the exact issue as well !

Comment: can you debug `newshape` and `order` values when error happens?

Comment: newshape = tuple: (5,); order = str: C

Comment: @alko, I saw your comment about this working on Python 2.something, so I just installed abd tried with Python 2.7.6 in Windows x86 32 bit with the same versions of the modules ==> same error. Also, with the newest Numpy (1.8.0) ==> same error. I see you have removed your comment, so I guess it's not working on your side after all...?

Comment: @Iye-Nico I removed comment as it was incorrect in regard to versions. I forgot to check matplotlib. Your code works for me with py 2.7, np 1.8.0, matplotlib 1.2.0, pd 1.12.0; ah, and it seems works for np 1.7.0

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but has anyone filed an issue on github about this?

Comment: @jseabold, I assumed the post form Jonathan March (see the accepted answer) was related to a reported bug. But after checking again I don't see any reference to a bug in his post, so maybe nobody has actually reported this. I'll have a look on pandas' github and create the the report if the issue is missing.

Comment: @Iye-Nico I already filed one. The issue seemed to have already been fixed though. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is matplotlib 1.3.1 with pandas 0.12 [integration bug](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23912890-Matplotlib-Pandas-plot-gives-TypeError-an-integer-is-required-):

> The workaround is to downgrade to matplotlib `1.3.0`. (Note, however, that this version of matplotlib contains a bug on systems which have fonts with non-ASCII font names, so you may need to pick your problem!). This downgrade will trigger a downgrade to numpy `1.7.1`, so you should then (again) upgrade to numpy `1.8.0`.
>   This error should be fixed in the upcoming Pandas `0.13`. However Pandas `0.13` may break some existing code (because pandas.Series is no longer a subclass of numpy.ndarray), so again, some hard choices may be required, at least in the short term.

Just checked, code works fine with matplotlib `1.3.0`:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.0'
>>> df.plot()
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x04E8B4F0>
>>> plt.show(_)
```

[image]

Comment: I confirm this works with Python 2.7.6, Matplotlib 1.3.0, NumPy 1.8.0 and Pandas 0.12.0. It also works with Python 3.3.2, Matplotlib 1.3.0, NumPy 1.7.1 and Pandas 0.12.0. Thank you @alko for your snappy answers, pointing out Jonathan March's post and testing on your side.

Answer (score 2):

I workaround the problem with following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df)
```

Comment: This solved it for me, too. Thanks @william! Much better than trying to upgrade/downgrade versions of pandas and numpy.

Comment: To preserve x-axis values...```fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot(df.index, df)```