# concatenating, pandas, and join_axes

Tags: python, pandas

I've been searching the web for an example of this, but haven't found anything.

Let `df1, df2, .. dfn` be pandas dataframes, indentically indexed.

What is happening when I run the command:

`pandas.concat([df1,..,dfn],axis=1,join_axes=[df1.index])`

It doesn't give me an error and provides a dataframe.  I've pasted all I could find in the documentation in relation to this.  What happens when there is a mismatch among the indices? How does pandas know to use the indexes of the other dataframes, I thought I might have to put all the indexes of the other `n-1` pandas dataframes.

Any tips?

**join_axes : list of Index objects
Specific indexes to use for the other n - 1 axes instead of performing inner/outer set logic**

Comment: I'm fairly certain only has 4 joints: inner, outer, left, and right. The default concat is to use 'outer'. If you pass a specific index, I'm pretty sure it does a left/right type of join. Meaning if the row is not present in the index you pass, it will insert a blank row. If the index does not contain a row, it will be removed. I think.

Comment: Yes, but the axis is 1, so we are dealing with adding on columns.

Comment: You're right. Glanced over that. Replace all of my "rows" with "columns."

Are you using ipython? These sort of questions can often be answered by just playing with a sample set of data and seeing what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Meaning of `n`

First of all, the `n` in `n-1` refers to the number of **dimensions** in each of the dataframes, not the number of dataframes. You can see that from [the source code at lines 938ff](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/221b493e6fc4fed9ef4a51eaea341f9d9c936de5/pandas/tools/merge.py#L938-L950):

```
def _get_new_axes(self):
    ndim = self._get_result_dim()
    new_axes = [None] * ndim

    if self.join_axes is None:
        for i in range(ndim):
            if i == self.axis:
                continue
            new_axes[i] = self._get_comb_axis(i)
    else:
        if len(self.join_axes) != ndim - 1:
            raise AssertionError("length of join_axes must not be "
                                 "equal to {0}".format(ndim - 1))
```

(Therefore, it should really not read `n-1` in the [documentation](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/221b493e6fc4fed9ef4a51eaea341f9d9c936de5/pandas/tools/merge.py#L719-L721). I guess this formulation is based on the common use example where the index passed with `join_axes` is that of **one of the dataframes**. The passed index could, though, also be a new, synthetic one.)

### Use of `join_axes`

The actual use `join_axes` is to **replace** the indexes of the dataframes that you want to concatenate with a different one (or actually one per dimension).

In this process, the values in each dataframe are simply **assigned** to the new indices, ignoring the index it contains. Furthermore, if one of the dataframes is longer (in any dimension) than the corresponding index, it will simply be truncated.

### Merging time series into one dataframe

What you might be trying to achieve is to combine a bunch of `Series` into a `DataFrame` and preserve their original (partially) non-matching indices.

```
pandas.concat([df1,..,dfn], axis=1, join='outer')
```

does that (with `join=outer`).

(However, when you want to plot the resulting dataframe, you might need to find a workaround, because [all columns are interrupted by NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13603181/512111).)

Answer (score 7):

**Join_axes** is deprecated. The supported way is now

```
pandas.concat([df1,..,dfn],axis=1).reindex(df1.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `join_axes=[df1.columns]`:

```
pandas.concat([df1,..,dfn],axis=1,join_axes=[df1.columns])
```

Comment: Do you mean to use df1.index?