# How Can I join the points of a plot if the data is not totally complete?

Tags: python, pandas, join, plot, subplot

I'm trying to join the points of a plot with at least 70 subplots, since it is not a scatter (because I can't use it since they are not series), I've tried marker = 'o-', but doesn't work. The data is in the format %mm-%yy, there are at least 6 different months (as a date column), and not for every column (Fund names) there exist any data in an specific month, however I want to join all the points from the same column even if they skipped any date. If I remove al the NaN points with df.dropna(), I will lose all the points.

I'm trying this, however it only joins the data that corresponds to following months.

```
df.plot(subplots = True, figsize = (20,20), layout = (14,5),legend=False,marker='o')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can plot for each column : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712406/3473645

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the following:

```
df.interpolate().plot(subplots = True, figsize = (20,120), layout = (24,3),marker='o', legend = True)
```

Adding interpolate() fix the error of NaN without delating data